# Owl carousel not looping

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm building an Owl Carousel and can't get it to loop. I am on the newest version 2.0.0-beta.2.4. My plugin configuration is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    navigation : true, 
    autoPlay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 500,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    dots: true,
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem: true,
    pagination: true
  });

});
```

I have 5 items in my slide as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the [newest version 2.1.4](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2).

The `singleItem` and other options are not supported. Please check `items` and [documentation](http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html).

Comment: Yup...that was it...was calling from a CDN and had my local and the CDN instance mixed up

Comment: @kawnah, please resolve this question.